# Fetching and Displaying Invoice Details in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Upon clicking on an Order No in filetredaddressdetails view, the application should redirect to the invoice view through orderid. The Order ID serves as a primary key in the Orders table, which helps fetch Order no, Grade, Subject, Item, Category, Price, Quantity, Address, Pin Code, Mobile, Email details from InvoiceApplications, GradeSubejctitemApplictaions and AddressDetails via foreign key references.

Tables with  column names

Orders- Id  OrderNo

AddressDetails-Id   OrderId(foreignkey) StudentId   StudentName ParentName  Address PinCode Mobile  Email

InvoiceApplications-Id  OrderId(fk)  GradeSubjectItemId(fk)

GradeSubjectItemApplications-Id(pk) GradeId(fk) SubjectId(fk)   AcademicYearId(fk)  ItemId(fk)  Quantity

ItemApplications-Id(pk) Name    CategoryId(fk)  Price

CategoryApplications-Id(pk) Name

GradeApplications- Id(pk)   Name    SyllabusId(fk)

SubjectApplications-Id(pk)  Name

This is the issue

```
System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=The specified type member 'GradeSubjectItemId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

This is in FilteredAddressDetails.js to redirect to Invoice View through orderId

```
'\<td\>\<a href="/Home/Invoice?orderId=' + item.OrderId + '"\>' + item.OrderNo + '\</a\>\</td\>' +
```

Homecontrolelr.cs

```
   public ActionResult Invoice(int orderId)
    {
        var invoiceDetails = (from ad in _db.AddressDetails
                              join o in _db.Orders on ad.OrderId equals o.Id
                              join ia in _db.InvoiceApplications on (int?)o.Id equals       ia.OrderId

                              join gsa in _db.GradeSubjectItemApplications on ia.GradeSubjectItemId equals gsa.Id
                              join ga in _db.GradeApplications on gsa.GradeId equals ga.Id
                              join item in _db.ItemApplications on gsa.ItemId equals item.Id
                              join ca in _db.CategoryApplications on item.CategoryId equals ca.Id
                              where o.Id == orderId
                              select new InvoiceViewModel
                              {
                                  StudentName = ad.StudentName,
                                  ParentName = ad.ParentName,
                                  Address = ad.Address,
                                  PinCode = ad.PinCode,
                                  Mobile = ad.Mobile,
                                  Email = ad.Email,
                                  Grade = ga.Name,
                                  Item = item.Name,
                                  Category = ca.Name,
                                  Quantity = gsa.Quantity,
                                  Price = item.Price
                              }).FirstOrDefault();


        return View(invoiceDetails);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question. **Minimal** is the key here. What is the purpose of all this code?